# what does the "start" parameter in the php function strcspn() does

Tags: php, php-5.5

i was trying to execute the following code

```
$string ='mynameisjenson';
echo strcspn( $string,'j',11);
```

the ouput am getting is 3 but really don't know how is gets 3.could any one
please explain this

Comment: this is amount of chars upto end of the string, because `j` is not found

Answer (score 1):

The `start` parameter tells `strcspn()` to start looking at that position in the string, instead of starting at the beginning of the string.

```
strcspn($string, 'j', 11)
```

is equivalent to

```
strcspn(substr($string, 11), 'j')
```

Position 11 in your string is the `s` character, so it's doing:

```
strcspn('son', 'j');
```

Since there's no `j` in that part of the string, it returns 3.